# How to parse long.MaxValue and ulong.MaxValue when doing conversion

Tags: c#, long-integer, ulong

I have tried to parse the maxvalue of long and ulong but it fails.  How to do that?

```
Int64.TryParse(value.ToString(), out resultInt)
```

`value` is Int64.MaxValue but the type of the `value` is double.

Comment: I don't understand. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Jimi, i have edited the question, please check that

Comment: Yes, I didn't see the `"G9"`part. Deleted the comment. It would work with `"N9"`, just in case...

Comment: Or BigInteger and `NumberStyles.Any`

Comment: Tried BigInteger but it is not working

Comment: This: `bool valid = BigInteger.TryParse(long.MaxValue.ToString("G9"), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out BigInteger resultInt);` returns `true`.  Not sure what you want to do with this.

Comment: @Jimi, deleted the code "G9". please check the code again and update

Comment: But, if you remove the `G9` format (which creates the *problem*), both `bool validL = long.TryParse(long.MaxValue.ToString(), out long resultLong);` and 
`bool validUL = ulong.TryParse(ulong.MaxValue.ToString(), out ulong resultULong);` would return `true`. Maybe explain why you're doing this. Is it just for testing?

Comment: The double type does not have enough precision to represent the value of long.MaxValue accurately.  It provides up to 15 significant digits, long.MaxValue requires 19.  So it must be rounded to get stored into a double and as Murphy dictates, the rounded value is slightly larger than long.MaxValue.  Kaboom.  Easy to see with the debugger btw.

Comment: @Jimi, can you please check my code once again and update here,

Answer (score 1):

## What's happening

Since `double` has the precision of [~15-17 digits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) it's not possible to stringify a `double` that was assigned `Int64.MaxValue` in a way that the string would represent exactly `9223372036854775807` (`Int64.MaxValue`, 19 digits).

## Solution

### A. Use `Int64`

Don't store integral values as `double`.

```
var l1 = long.MaxValue;
var l2 = long.Parse(l1.ToString());
Console.WriteLine( $"Diff: {l2-l1}");
// Diff: 0
```

### B. Fudge

With `ToString("F0")` (and few other formats) it's possible to get quite close; just 1 above `Int64.MaxValue` (`9223372036854775808`).

You could try to trim the double string.

```
public static (long L, bool IsHack) GetLongUpToMaxValue(string str) {
    try
    {
        return (long.Parse(str, NumberStyles.Any), false);
    } 
    catch( OverflowException )
    {
        var ul = ulong.Parse(str, NumberStyles.Any);
        if((ul - long.MaxValue) == 1) return (long.MaxValue, true);
        throw;
    }
}
```

### Test code

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
 Console.WriteLine($"{"SRC", -25}{"STR", -25}{"DIFF", -10}{"HACK?", -10}");
 foreach(long l in new[]{Int64.MaxValue, Int64.MaxValue-1, Int64.MaxValue-2, Int64.MaxValue-100, Int64.MaxValue-1000, Int64.MinValue, Int64.MinValue+1, Int64.MinValue+2, 1000, -1000, 0})
 {
     double d = l;
     var dStr = d.ToString("F0");// F,G19
     (long l2, bool isHack) = GetLongUpToMaxValue(d.ToString("F0"));
     Console.WriteLine($"{l2, -25}{dStr, -25}{l - l2, -10}{isHack}");
 }
```

### Output

```
// .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0
SRC                      STR                      DIFF      HACK?
9223372036854775807      9223372036854775808      0         True
9223372036854775807      9223372036854775808      -1        True
9223372036854775807      9223372036854775808      -2        True
9223372036854775807      9223372036854775808      -100      True
9223372036854774784      9223372036854774784      23        False
-9223372036854775808     -9223372036854775808     0         False
-9223372036854775808     -9223372036854775808     1         False
-9223372036854775808     -9223372036854775808     2         False
1000                     1000                     0         False
-1000                    -1000                    0         False
0                        0                        0         False
```

## Examples of different formats

Here are some examples for few `ToString` formats.

```
var l1 = Int64.MaxValue;
Console.WriteLine($"Int64.MaxValue: {l1}");
double d = l1;

foreach(var x in new []{"C", "E", "F", "F0", "G", "G15", "G30", "N", "P", "R", "##########################"}) {
    var dStr = d.ToString(x);
    Console.WriteLine($"{x} {dStr}");

    try { Console.WriteLine($"\t long diff: {long.Parse(dStr, NumberStyles.Any) - long.MaxValue}");} 
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine($"\t long.Parse: {ex.Message}");};

    try { Console.WriteLine($"\t ulong diff: {ulong.Parse(dStr, NumberStyles.Any) - long.MaxValue}");} 
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine($"\t ulong.Parse: {ex.Message}");};

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

### Output

```
// .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0
Int64.MaxValue: 9223372036854775807
C $9,223,372,036,854,775,808.00
         long.Parse: Value was either too large or too small for an Int64.
         ulong diff: 1

E 9.223372E+018
         long diff: -36854775807
         ulong diff: 18446744036854775809

F 9223372036854775808.00
         long.Parse: Value was either too large or too small for an Int64.
         ulong diff: 1

F0 9223372036854775808
         long.Parse: Value was either too large or too small for an Int64.
         ulong diff: 1

G 9.223372036854776E+18
         long.Parse: Value was either too large or too small for an Int64.
         ulong diff: 193

G15 9.22337203685478E+18
         long.Parse: Value was either too large or too small for an Int64.
         ulong diff: 4193

G30 9223372036854775808
         long.Parse: Value was either too large or too small for an Int64.
         ulong diff: 1

N 9,223,372,036,854,775,808.00
         long.Parse: Value was either too large or too small for an Int64.
         ulong diff: 1

P 922,337,203,685,477,580,800.00%
         long.Parse: Input string was not in a correct format.
         ulong.Parse: Input string was not in a correct format.

R 9.223372036854776E+18
         long.Parse: Value was either too large or too small for an Int64.
         ulong diff: 193

########################## 9223372036854780000
         long.Parse: Value was either too large or too small for an Int64.
         ulong diff: 4193
```

Comment: The question change few times. Thanks for bringing my attention to this. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @HansPassant Now knowing that the question had `double` meaning (badam tsh...) I updated the answer.